# Neo4j ETL takes time to migrate from RDBMS to Graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying the option of going with ETL as in Production we would like to use this option but once I start connecting my RDBMS to Graph as mentioned in the link https://neo4j.com/labs/etl-tool, it is taking a lot of time as below:

[image]

Firstly, the goal is to create a POC for ProductSales correlation, the current dataset I am having has 175000 rows(can reduce the size) from two tables. Once we know that it works then we look more into this. What would you recommend to get the graph for this?

Comment: Advice: embed the image Logs-ETL into the post. Mention clearly how much time it takes, not just "lot of time".

Comment: It is still going on..hovering over a disabled START MAPPING button. Please find the last 4-5 lines of the logs : - Crawling routines
- Retrieved 0 routines
- Not retrieving synonyms, since this was not requested
- Not retrieving sequences, since this was not requested
Mapping.....